# Ruby on Rails フォームをうまく作成できません

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Railsを勉強中です。現在、フォームの作成で入力画面を作成しています。

index.html.erbで以下のエラーが発生してしまい、うまくいきません。
解決策を教えていただけると幸いです。

```
ArgumentError in Contact#index
First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty

<%= form_for(@contact, url:{controller:'contact', action:'create'}) do |f| %>
```

contact_controller.rb

```
class ContactController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @msg = "メッセージだよ"
  end

  def create
    @contact = Contactkun.new(new_params)

    if @contact.save
      @msg = "送信完了"
    else
      @msg = "エラー"
    end
  end

  private
  def new_params
    params.require(:contactkun).permit(:name, :content)
  end
end
```

contactkun.rb

```
class Contactkun < ApplicationRecord
  # フォームのバリデーション
  validates :name, presence: true
  validates :contact, presence: true
end
```

index.html.erb

```
<p><%= @msg %></p>

<%= form_for(@contact, url:{controller:'contact', action:'create'}) do |f| %>

  <% if @contact.errors.any? %>
    <% @contact.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
      <p><%= message %></p>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>

<table>
  <tr><td>名前</td><td><%= f.text_field :name %></td></tr>
  <tr><td>内容</td><td><%= f.text_area :content %></td></tr>
  <tr><td></td><td><%= f.submit "問い合わせる" %></td></tr>
</table>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<%= form_for(@contact, url:{controller:'contact', action:'create'}) do |f| %>
```

で`@contact`がnilなのでエラーになっています。

コントローラの`index`メソッドに

```
@contact = Contactkun.new
```

を追加してください。

ただ、このコードだと命名規則がRailsの流儀からはずれてるとか、例えば`@contact.save`に失敗したときのために同じフォームを別に用意しないといけないなどいろいろ問題がありそうです。

1から作るのではなく、scaffoldで生成されるコードをベースにした方がいいです。また、Railsの基本的な作法がわからないなら、[Rails tutorial](http://railstutorial.jp)などで基礎を一通り勉強されるのが良いでしょう。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。いろいろ問題がありそうなので、scaffoldでまた作り直してみます。